# What do I have to garbage collect in a C++ destructor

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor, smart-pointers, raii

I'm writing a C++ destructor (I hope that's the right term; I'm new to C++) and I'm not positive on what exactly I need to garbage collect.  Let's say I have 2 pointers as instance variables do I need to garbage collect them? What about if I have an object as an instance variable? Or a pointer to an object?

I'm just a little fuzzy on what exactly needs to be deleted and what is automatically cleaned up.

Thanks

Comment: Pedantic note: you do not "garbage collect" things in C++. You *delete* them.

Comment: C++ does not have a garbage collector. Are you trying to write one, or are you just trying to delete an object in the destructor? And why aren't you using smart pointers?

Comment: if you coming from other languages, C++ destructor concept means, what you dirty, you should clean it yourself. You can't be careless about it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

General rule of thumb is... if you called `new`, call `delete`. If you called `new[]`, call `delete[]`. If you're accessing these pointers outside of the class and effectively sharing them, you'll want to be careful about the "owning" object `delete`ing the shared objects while they're still in use. Garbage collection isn't quite the right term. You want to `destroy` the object and `free` its memory. This is what `delete`/`delete[]` does. `new`/`new[]` allocate memory and `construct` an object.

In C++, there is no garbage collector. You must "manually" handle it. That's not to say that it's all tedium. You'll probably get into using **smart pointers** to handle some of this logic for you. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417481/pointers-smart-pointers-or-shared-pointers) for more information.

Comment: The only answer that mentioned ownership.  +1!

Comment: So if I have a pointer to an object as an instance field, and let's suppose that no one else knows about it, then I would have to delete the object but not the pointer...Is that correct?

Comment: The syntax is along the lines of `delete Address`. A pointer is effectively some data storing the address in memory of an object. So, if you have `int* Number;`, you should use `delete Number;` to delete what `Number` points to. You are not deleting the pointer, per se, but what the pointer points to. The syntax merely wants an address and the pointer stores the address.

Answer (score 3):

You must `delete` every pointer you allocate with `new`. It's that simple, and it's that complicated; you must not lose track of any pointer allocated by `new` until you have `delete`d it.

Also, you need to make sure that if you use `new[]` to allocate a pointer, you call `delete[]` to deallocate it.

It's not about what pointers you happen to have in a class instance. You need to know who *owns* them (the owner is the one responsible for deleting them). If your object owns those pointers, then it should delete them. If it doesn't own them, then it shouldn't.

This is also why experienced C++ programmers avoid naked pointers where possible. Smart pointers allow you to express ownership types semantically in the language. That way, you don't have to keep track of who owns what; you know who owns it by the type of smart pointer being used.

Comment: You may want to mention the difference between `new`, `new[]`, `delete`, and `delete[]`

Answer (score 3):

You must call `delete` on every space you created using `new`, `delete[]` on every area created using `new[]`, and `free` on everything you got using `malloc`.

You should also close any sockets you opened, and clear up any other OS resources your class owns.

Note: this is not called garbage collection. Garbage collection is when this process happens automatically, as part of a library or language runtime, not when you do it explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You should start by learning about "Resource Acquisition is Initialization" (RAII) and smart pointers (`shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`). This is *the* idiom you have to know in C++ if you come from other languages.

Usual practice says that whatever you allocated in your constructor must be deallocated in your destructor (see other answers to know how). Event better, try to use values as much as possible and `new` as less as possible.
C++ loves the stack, and stack allocation and deallocation are automatic and cheap (no new, no delete). Use references and const-references instead of pointers.

If you *really* need dynamic memory, try to use one of the smart pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Any memory you allocate using new operator needs to be freed.

You allocate memory by doing:

```
int * p1 = new int[5];
p2 = new int;
```

and you delete it by doing:

```
delete[] p1
delete p2;
```

If you are playing with Classes, you need to do the same thing in constructors (allocate) and destructors (deallocate).

Answer (score 2):

In an ideal world, nothing. There are smart pointers and containers for every pattern. Sometimes, you will have to write your own, or augment existing implementations, but much of what you need exists already.

For an array, start with `std::array` and `std::vector`. For objects, read up on smart pointers and shared pointers. As a *generalization*: if you need to call `delete`, `delete[]` or `free`, you have usually headed down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to garbage collect all pointers that you don't no longer need. Otherwise you would have the dangling pointer problem.

Comment: C++ does not have garbage collection. You're as confused as the person who asked the question.

Comment: That's not a dangling pointer, that's a memory leak. Dangling pointer is what happens if you free it, and then try to use it.

Comment: its memory leak!, dangling is if you delete and then try to access it!