# Do I need to clean up non-pointer data members?

Tags: c++, destructor

If I don't use `new` to allocate the data members of a class, is there still any clean-up that needs to be done in the destructor? For example, in the following case, will I need to `delete` the vector? Or does it depend on `MyType`?

```
class A {
  A();
  ~A();
  MyType x;
  std::vector<MyType> v;
};
A::A() {
  x = MyType(42);
  v = std::vector<MyType>(5);
}
A::~A() {
  // what goes here?
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be pedantic, **it depends** on what `MyType` is. If you have `typedef char* MyType` and you allocate memory for `MyType`, and you want that memory to be owned by the object, then yes, you need a destructor.

Otherwise, you don't need to free memory for anything that wasn't allocated with `new` or `malloc`, so no.

**Your class shouldn't even have a destructor at all.** There's a general consensus that you should only have a destructor when you actually need it. Having a destructor also implies implementing an assignment operator and copy constructor (**the rule of three**). If you're not managing any memory, it's better to rely on the ones provided by the compiler - i.e. the compiler **will generate** these three if you don't.

Also, your **constructor** should look like this:

```
A::A() : x(42), v(5){
}
```

Otherwise your members will be initialized and then assigned to, which is wasteful.

Comment: In this particular case, no need for a dtor.  Just keep in mind that the "R" in "RAII" stands for *resource*, not *memory*.  Sometimes you will need to release something other than memory in a dtor.

Comment: @JohnDibling but this(at least the second part) is based on the assumption that resources are released when their particular owners are destroyed. So if `MyType` acquires a resource and releases it in its destructor, it's ok.

Comment: In that context: one object should manage one resource, max. If you need to manage 2 resources, wrap them in 2 members each of which manages one resource.

Answer (score 4):

Your class does not need an explicit destructor. The `vector`'s destructor will be invoked automatically anyway. And since the vector object itself (as opposed to the data inside) is not dynamic, you don't have to `delete` it. In fact, that'd be a syntax error, as `v` is not a pointer.

Comment: So the "rule of three" does not apply in this case, as I only need an explicit constructor?

Comment: Rule of 3 is copy ctor, dtor and overloaded =.  Not other ctor's.

Answer (score 1):

The destructors are automatically called, so you don't need to do that. Also, for pointers use [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/417481/1203803) (such as `std::unique_ptr`) instead of `delete`ing them manually.

```
class A {
  A();
  ~A();
  MyType x;
  std::vector<MyType> v;
};
A::A() : x(42), v(5) { }
A::~A() {
  // x.~MyType() implicitly called.
  // v.~std::vector<MyType>() implicitly called.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The vector is automatically deleted at time of destruction. However, if you store pointers in a vector, E.g. If you say vector<Foo *> v;, you'll need write code to delete the pointers in the vector. One way to avoid this is to use vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> or vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to. Their constructors will be called implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

For class *A* no, you don't, since it doesn't have any pointer member allocated using *new* or *malloc*.

Beware that if your class/struct *MyType* have any pointers as a member, the destructor of *MyType* is the responsible to free the memory of such pointer, but you don't have to worry with that in class *A*, since when its destructor is called, the destructor of the vector calls the destructor of *MyType*.

Comment: Unless `MyType` is a pointer, in which case no destructor is called and you'll leak memory.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Is it right that `MyType` could only be a pointer if it's been `typedef`fed?

Comment: @Andreas or with a define `#define MyType X*` :)