# use std::ostream passed by ref

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, std

in my code, an init function of my class is like this:

```
void MyApp::start(std::ostream & log_output)
{
    theLogOutput = log_output;
    // do stuff...
}
```

and `theLogOutput` is declared into the .h file:

```
std::ostream theLogOutput;
```

but the compiler gives me this error:

`Error   10  error C2248: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>'`

Comment: `std::ostream` doesn't provide a (public) copy constructor.

Comment: Use shared_ptr of ostream

Comment: Sometimes pointers are a good idea... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417481/pointers-smart-pointers-or-shared-pointers for which one you need.

Comment: @NeilKirk Which will mean that he can't use `std::cout`.

Comment: Streams are not copyable; they are flows of data, not containers, so this makes sense.

Comment: @NeilKirk Because `std::cout` isn't dynamically allocated.  (FWIW, the only time I've seen dynamically allocated stream objects, they had lifetimes determined by external events, so you couldn't use the smart pointers on them either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pass by reference works fine here, the problem is that `theLogOutput = log_output` incurs a copy.

As commenters point out, `std::ostream` cannot be copied (as it does not have a copy constructor). There is some things you can do though:

- If the lifetime of the `log_output` object is static (or otherwise long enough), you can make the global log stream a pointer to `std::ostream` and have it hold the address of said object (i.e. `theLogOutput = &log_output`, you may consider taking the stream as a pointer already to make the intent clearer). This would, for example, work for `std::cout`, `std::cin` or any `std::ostream` you allocate locally in your `main`. Make sure you clarify the lifetime requirements in your documentation to `startApp`.
- Use `std::shared_ptr<std::ostream>` everywhere to keep a shared reference to a single stream.
- With C++11, you can move a `std::ostream`

Last but not least, declaring global variables in `.h` files is rarely a good idea. If the file is included into multiple translation units, you get errors due to the symbol being defined multiple times. At best, it should be declared `extern` in the header and defined in only one translation unit (.cpp file).

Comment: thanks Alexander, but after I've declared as shared_ptr, how can I set the reference?

Comment: Don't use a reference at all: `void MyApp::start(std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> log_output)`. `shared_ptr` can be copied without copying the underlying object. Note that this means you need to always wrap your `ostream` in a `shared_ptr`, which takes over all lifetime management. This is why, as @James Kanze remarked, it won't work with `std::cout` or other streams of static lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

An `std::ostream` is not copiable; it has mutable state and is
polymorphic, which make copy and assignment problematic.  In
C++11, it is movable, if you want the caller to give up all
posession (but you'll have to explicitly move it).  Most of the
time, however, you don't want a copy of the string, nor unique
ownership; in those cases, you make the member a reference as
well, or if the class must support assignment, you make the
member a pointer, and take the address of the parameter.

In your case, since you're modifying an already existing variable,
you need to use the pointer; a reference must be initialized, and
cannot be reseated once it has been initialized.